# how to avoid calling percentile_cont twice in a case clause to replace null with zero?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, null, percentile-cont

I need to calculate the median transaction amount for each customer in the past 52 weeks, but percentile_cont returns NULL if there's no transaction for a particular customer. In such a case, I have to replace NULL with zero, I acheived this by using a CASE clause in sql, however I am using PERCENTILE_CONT twice for this purpose which makes the query slow for a huge list of customers to process. is there a better way to use the PERCENTILE_CONT only once inside the CASE clause?

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer,

       CASE WHEN 
       PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) 
       WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 
       transamt) OVER 
       (PARTITION BY
      customer) IS NOT NULL THEN

      PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN 
      GROUP (ORDER BY transamt) 
      OVER (PARTITION BY
      customer)

      ELSE 0
      END  AS median_amt

FROM trans_table

WHERE trans_date BETWEEN DATEADD(WEEK, -52, GETDATE() ) AND GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to "...percentile_cont returns NULL if there's no transaction for a particular customer...", it could be a data issue or by design there could be entries for a customer without any transactions could have `trans_date` in the past 52 weeks but `transamt` is null. If that's the case, maybe this work for you by changing `order by transamt` to the following:

```sql
select distinct 
       customer,
       percentile_cont(0.5) within group 
       (order by case when transamt is null then 0 else transamt end) 
       over (partition by customer) as median_amt
  from trans_table;
```

Second guess: if percentile_cont() return NULL then show 0. Using coalesce().

```
select distinct customer,
       coalesce(percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by transamt) over (partition by customer),0) as median_amt
  from trans_table;
```

Comment: no, in your solution percentile_cont considers zero in place any null. what I'm expecting is to have zero instead of NULL if that customer has no transaction at all. otherwise, percentile_cont should do its expected calculation.

Comment: @Arash could you please present some sample data to illustrate what it looks like when a customer has no transaction at all in your table?

Comment: @Arash try coalesce(). Please see updated query.

Comment: thanks it seems coalesce () is the answer as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I tried COALESCE() function as JHH suggested and didn't see much difference performance wise. it seems COALESCE() is internally a CASE statement.

However when I switched to:

```
isnull(percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by transamt) over 
(partition by customer),0)
```

the computation time dropped by a factor of 2.

I don't know if this can be generalized to any scenarios or is it merely my particular query.

Comment: yes this is generally correct - there used to be a Microsoft connect item about this type of thing open since 2008 (way back machine link https://web.archive.org/web/20160617042004/https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/336002/unnecessarily-bad-performance-for-coalesce-subquery)  - but that site was retired years ago.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new solution to speed up things called `APPROX_PERCENTILE_CONT` but it only [applies to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/approx-percentile-cont-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

- SQL Server 2022 (16.x)
- Azure SQL Database
- Azure SQL Managed Instance

You can now use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer,

       CASE WHEN 
       APPROX_PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) 
       WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 
       transamt) OVER 
       (PARTITION BY
      customer) IS NOT NULL THEN

      APPROX_PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN 
      GROUP (ORDER BY transamt) 
      OVER (PARTITION BY
      customer)

      ELSE 0
      END  AS median_amt

FROM trans_table

WHERE trans_date BETWEEN DATEADD(WEEK, -52, GETDATE() ) AND GETDATE()
```

In this [example](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-blog/announcing-general-availability-of-approximate-percentile/bc-p/3773395/emcs_t/S2h8ZW1haWx8dG9waWNfc3Vic2NyaXB0aW9ufExGSUlVOThXWDE4QzYxfDM3NzMzOTV8U1VCU0NSSVBUSU9OU3xoSw#M1377) it pushed the speed from ~13 seconds to ~1.5 seconds.

Comment: true, it's faster. but you are still calling percentile twice in the case statement.